# why can't I see some of my classes when I export project to jar

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project which works well in eclipse IDE. this project has about 7 classes. when I export this project and import it for other use, I am only able to see 5 of my classes. I don't why I can't the other 2 classes even-though they are all in the same folder. I am using eclipse IDE and I could this all the 7 java files in the src folder and the classes in the bin folder.

Comment: Are all the classes public?

Comment: please add for all you classes definition like this: `xxx class Foo {}` also make sure your exported jar is up to date.

Comment: @MarcinŁoś yes all the classes are public